# How to access the table names from different component in tDBInput through SQL query in talend

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

[image]
[image]
[image]

I want to access the table names from tFileInputDelimited, so how to write SQL squery in tDBInput so that I can able to access the data of that table.please just see the image you can understand, there is SQL query which i have written.

I tried various ways but it's not working.

Comment: what do you mean by access the table names from tFileInputDelimited  ? are you stocking your table names in a csv file ? please show us your file and what your output ?

Comment: It's a txt file contains table_name column, so I am asking how to write SQL query without mentioning the table name. For example select * from (tFileInputDelimited.Table_Name) like that??

Comment: You have to use a tFileInputRaw order then a tFileInputDelimited .

Comment: link the tFileInputRaw  -> tlog and see the result ;) . The tFileInputRaw   will return you an object that you have to parse then get the table names the put them  in a tSetGlobalVar then yse the global variables in your tDbInput  . Hope it helps . you have to give it a try then tell us if you are stack and what you tried

Comment: if you link your tFileInputDelimited -> tlog . what is your output could you mention that in the question ?

Comment: It's showing SQL syntax error for above query you have shared

Comment: Updated my answer , could you get the query i posted and tell me what error you are getting

Comment: It's showing like SQL syntax error, can we use tFixedFlowInput instaed of tfileinputdelimited. In that tFixedFlowInput we can use inline content option

Comment: show the error you are getting and in which component we can not guess the errors here ? update your question and show us

Comment: I have added the picture of error

Comment: if you do this tdbinput -> tlogrow with this query  select * from "SYS_BIC"."inbound.ecc.p2r.cs/CV_JEST"   .  what it will return ?

Comment: in your sap environement what is the query you are using ? select * from "SYS_BIC"."inbound.ecc.p2r.cs/CV_JEST" ???

Comment: Yes this is the query i use in sap

Comment: try to add a \  before every value in your file \"SYS_BIC\".\"inbound.ecc.p2r.cs/CV_JEST\"  and so on

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, and if you really need to take a picture, learn how to take screenshots. Taking pictures of monitor with a camera is just awful.

Answer (score 0):

try using this query

```
  "select  * from "+((String)globalMap.get("row2.Table_name"))+""
```

I supposed that your getting the right result from  tFileInputDelimited   to check that you have to link

**tFileInputDelimited -> tLogRow**